# OpenLayers 3: Reload failed tiles

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3 with a Zoomify tile source. Based on various conditions I have to re-render my set of tiles on the server side and display the new set to the user as soon as possible.

What I would want to do is to display a single zoom level as soon as this is rendered on the server side, and OpenLayers automatically try to get the other tiles when they are ready. But I found that once a tile is not found OpenLayers won't try to reload it afterwards.

I am trying to do this manually and I want to catch the tileloaderror event on the Zoomify Source. The event is triggered correctly and I receive the Tile url that was not found. What would I want to do is to add a function here on a timeout to retry to load the tile but I didn't find anything in the API.

Is there any method to try to reload a tile if it fails ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has encountered this issue, this will be supported natively by OpenLayers. [Reference](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5270)

Comment: So... how do you make it reload the images (Tiles) that failed to load on the first try?